# DBAN Hangs at PCI (sysfs)

Tags: laptop, dban

I'm running "Derik's Boot and Nuke 2.2.6 beta". When I get to a blue screen (not a BSOD) after booting to the live CD the following is printed...

> Derik's Boot and Nuke 2.2.6 (beta) is
>   starting.
>
> Waiting for USB devices to
>   register..........................done.
>
> PCI (sys)

After that, it just sits there **forever...** Any advice, other than an older version of DBAN?
I have gotten this version of DBAN to work on an older machine before.

Comment: DBAN is pointless use MHDD Secure Erase http://hddguru.com/software/2005.10.02-MHDD/. MHDD erases using functions built into the HD's controller. So it is much faster and also erases parts of the HD DBAN cannot.

Comment: Thanks for the comments @jb48394! I will try to remember to use this next time I need to wipe a drive clean. I use DBAN because it offers Gutmann (35 passes). The governemtn uses it, so why not me? :)

Comment: @David: Gutmann's algorithm was already useless by the time it had been published ([according to himself](http://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~pgut001/pubs/secure_del.html#Epilogue)), and was never used by "the" government (or by *any* government, americans).

Comment: I gave MHDD a shot, using version 4.6, and it was unable to detect the HDD in the laptop I was trying to wipe. Version 4.5 supports ATA/SCSI, so I probably just grabbed the wrong iso.

Comment: I'm very sure that DBAN works. I have used it numerous times. If you don't want to waste a CD attempting it, just make your flash drive boot-able with the ISO on it. Let me know if you have any problems.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to disable your card reader or other devices in BIOS.

Comment: Wow. Quick, Simple, and easy answer that works. Thank you so much. 




P.S. It was the card reader...

Comment: Flas Media Reader was the only device I needed to disable as well. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Hmm. Firmware F.16 on an HP dv9347cl doesn't seem to offer the ability to disable the card reader. :-\